# Adding up all the elements of each column in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

So I have this dummy 2D array:

```java
int mat[][] = {
        {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90},
        {15, 25, 35, 45},
        {27, 29, 37, 48},
        {32, 33, 39, 50, 51, 89}};
```

I want to add up all the values by columns so it would add `10 + 15 + 27 + 32` and return `84` and so on. I have this so far:

```java
public void sum(int[][] array) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < array.length; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < array[rows].length; columns++) {
            System.out.print(array[rows][columns] + "\t");
            count += array[0][0];
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("total = " + count);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this? Also the `System.out.print(array[rows][columns] + "\t" );` prints the array out by rows, is there a way to print it out by columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible Solution would be to first find maximum size of all sub arrays and iterate that many times to find sum of each column avoiding unavailable values.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mat[][] = {{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90},
            {15, 25, 35, 45},
            {27, 29, 37, 48},
            {32, 33, 39, 50, 51, 89},
    };

    // Find maximum possible length of sub array
    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        if (maxLength < mat[i].length)
            maxLength = mat[i].length;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {
            // Avoid if no value available for
            // ith column from this subarray
            if (i < mat[j].length)
                sum += mat[j][i];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of Column " + i + " = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArrayList to get the sum of all the columns.

```
public static void sum(int[][] array) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
            if (sums.size() <= column) {
                sums.add(column, 0);
            }
            int curVal = sums.get(column);
            sums.remove(column);
            sums.add(column, curVal + array[row][column]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sums.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Sum of column " + i + " = " + sums.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*…and the same with lambda:*

```java
int[] array = Arrays.stream(mat)
  .reduce((a1, a2) -> IntStream.range(0, Math.max(a1.length, a2.length))
      .map(i -> i < a1.length && i < a2.length ? a1[i] + a2[i]
          : i < a1.length ? a1[i] : a2[i] ).toArray()).get();
```

gets the sums of each column in the `int[] array`:

```
[84, 107, 141, 183, 101, 149, 70, 80, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method to summarise the elements of the rows of the matrix by the columns:

```java
int[][] matrix = {
        {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90},
        {15, 25, 35, 45},
        {27, 29, 37, 48},
        {32, 33, 39, 50, 51, 89}};

int[] arr = Arrays.stream(matrix)
        // summarize in pairs
        // the rows of the matrix
        .reduce((row1, row2) -> IntStream
                // iterate over the indices
                // from 0 to maximum row length
                .range(0, Math.max(row1.length, row2.length))
                // summarize in pairs the elements of two rows
                .map(i -> (i < row1.length ? row1[i] : 0) +
                        (i < row2.length ? row2[i] : 0))
                // an array of sums
                .toArray())
        // the resulting array
        .get();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [84, 107, 141, 183, 101, 149, 70, 80, 90]
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Sum of 2 different 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65377368/14838237)

• [How to calculate the average value of each column in 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453426/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative.

The supplied data.

```
int mat[][] = { { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 },
        { 15, 25, 35, 45 }, { 27, 29, 37, 48 },
        { 32, 33, 39, 50, 51, 89 }, };
```

First, find the maximum length of the array in which to store the sum.

```
int max = Arrays.stream(mat).mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().orElse(0);
```

Allocate the new array to hold the sums.

```
int[] sums = new int[max];
```

Now just use the `Arrays.setAll` method to sum them, taking care
to not exceed the current array's length.

```
for (int[] arr : mat) {
    Arrays.setAll(sums, i-> i < arr.length ? sums[i] + arr[i] : sums[i]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums));
```

Prints

```
[84, 107, 141, 183, 101, 149, 70, 80, 90]
```